# min-height not working. Div disappears in certain browser sizes

Tags: html, css

This is my first time posting and I am new to web development so please bear with me!

On parts of our site we have a white div with text content. I have positioned it so it's inline with other elements on the page.  I have been trying to sort out a way that makes the div (#contacttextcontainer) more responsive so that the text is readable regardless of the browser window size.  I tried overflow:auto which did contain the text within the div (adding scroll bars when needed) but there is also the issue that at certain browser sizes the div will completely collapse.  I tried min-height (display:block, min-height: 100%... and I tried specific pxs as well). but none seem to work....am I missing something??`

I have been testing on Safari.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!  Thank You!!!!

The HTML:

```
    <div id="contacttextcontainer"> 
     <p></p>
     <p>test test test.</p>
     <p>test</p>
     <p>test test test test test</p>
     <p>STUDIO HOURS;</p>
     <p></p>
     <p>9-4:30 Mon-Fri and by appointment</p>
     <p></p>
     <p>CONTACT;</p>
     <p>555-555-5555</p>
     <p>test test test</p>
    </div>
```

The CSS

```
    #contacttextcontainer {
font-size: 16px; 
text-align: center; 
font-family: courier;
position: absolute;
top:335px;
left:315px;
right: 260px;
bottom: 115px;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
overflow: auto;
   }
```

Comment: what exactly do you want the div to do? expand vertically with the text?

Comment: Hi MattyF.  That's a good question. It's made me rethink this and maybe I"m asking for something that isn't possible. I guess that what's bothering me is that the div disappears at a fairly large browser size (likely bc I've set strict placement with top, bottom etc.).  Expanding vertically with the text might solve the look visually so if you have a solution that would be great!  Thank you so much for your prompt response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if we look at your original html / css we get this: http://jsfiddle.net/svJUQ/ and by removing the bottom position we get this: http://jsfiddle.net/svJUQ/2/ - when there isn't a bottom position or height specified for the div it's height is set to default (`height: auto;`) and the div will expand to fit its contents. There is no need to change the default value of overflow which is `overflow: visible;` unless you want scrolling content or hidden content. Please let me know if that isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks MattyF.  That works well.  We originally put the position top/bottom etc. properties in because we were concerned about lining it up with other elements but I think this makes more sense.Thanks for your help!!!!